# WebConfig httpOnlyCookies setting not setting cookie value

Tags: security, cookies, web-config

I have a web config which looks like this:

```
 <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true" />
```

I want my cookies to be only accessible server side and also only by SSL. I also locked the node because I wanted to make sure that nothing else was changing it.

But once I create a cookie in my application it is not created with HttpOnly as true and Secure as false. The code looks like this:

```
 public void CreateCookie(string name, NameValueCollection values) {
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(name) {
                Expires = DateTime.Parse(values["Expiry"])
            };

            cookie.Values.Add(values);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
```

However, if I manually set the values in my cookie creation code it will set the httpOnly and Secure settings correctly.

Does anyone know why my web config isn't affecting my code?

I am using localhost in Visual Studio

If it helps the code which creates my cookie is in a separate project, my repository which is a C# class library. I set the same setting in my app.Config but it still didn't make an effect